# Oracle : ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.PATIENT2_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: oracle

am getting this error after creating 3 times this table patient..
here is the sql for patient :

```
CREATE TABLE  "PATIENT2" 
   (    "PATIENTID" NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "F_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "L_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AGE" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BLOODGROUP" VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREETADDRESS" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MOBILENUMBER" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "REGISTRATION" DATE, 
    "DOCTORID" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PATIENT2_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PATIENTID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PATIENT2_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DOCTORID")
      REFERENCES  "DOCTOR1" ("DOCTORID") ENABLE
   )
/
```

here for doctor :

```
CREATE TABLE  "DOCTOR1" 
   (    "DOCTORID" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "F_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "L_NAME" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STREETADDRESS" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXPERTISE" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "DOCTOR1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DOCTORID") ENABLE
   )
/
```

and the data i wanna add, then am getting this error ORA-02291

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES(1,'Barry','Allen',24,'M','O+','Hollywood St','Texas','52311300','5-MAY-2017', 7);
```

can anyone help me in showing me where to correct?

Comment: A doctor's record  has to be created first before adding a patient.

Comment: As an aside, the error says that you are creating object in SYSTEM schema. You'd better create your own schema and avoid working as SYSTEM. Another hint, you only need double quotes if you want to create object with lower case letters, spaces, ... For your objects, you dont' need quotes

Comment: THANKS, CAN SOMEONE TELL ME HOW TO DELETE a table, which havent being populated at all?
am using 10g express edition

Comment: drop table XXX cascade constraints

Comment: CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
 APPOINTMENTID number(2) NOT NULL,
 PATIENTID number(5) NOT NULL,
 DOCTORID number(2) NOT NULL,
 DATETIME date,
 CONSTRAINT pk_appointment PRIMARY KEY (appointmentid),
 CONSTRAINT fk_patient FOREIGN KEY (patientid),
 CONSTRAINT fk_doctor FOREIGN KEY (doctorid), 
 REFERENCES DOCTOR(doctorid), REFERENCES PATIENT(patientid)
     );

this one am getting "

ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: Foreign key syntax looks like this: `CONSTRAINT fk_patient FOREIGN KEY (patientid) REFERENCES patient(patientid)` - don't put commas in the middle or move the REFERENCES clause.

Comment: OK, after correcting it, and now am populating it, 1st data was created but when am inputing 3RD data amd getting "ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BHAVISH.FK_PATIENT) violated - parent key not found,
here is the data "INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT VALUES(3,3,6,'7-MAY-2017'); "

but the fact is that the first 2 data was created...then why getting error on 3rd?